# Importing GeneratedSource in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build-system

I'm generating some source files via ANTLR. I want to use those files while writing my own source code.

When I use the `generateGrammarSource` task the code is perfectly generated but goes to the `build\generated-src` directory. When I import classes from that directory, both my `build` task and the `make` project compiles successfully. But *IntelliSense* is generating a metric ton of errors and warnings (mostly indicating that the imports are non-existent - `Cannot resolve Symbol`, even though they really are there).

Is this a problem with *IntelliJ*, what can I do to appease *IntelliSense*, so I can continue my work in peace?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should have the following setup:

```
def generatedDir = 'src/main/gen'
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs += [generatedDir]
        }
    }
}

task generateGrammarSource // need to generate the file under src/main/gen

compileTask.dependsOn(generateGrammarSource) // don't know the exact name of the compile task

clean << {
   project.file(generatedDir).deleteDir()
}
```

You'll also need to add the generated sources to *IntelliJ*, google for it.

Comment: It's all setup correctly by the `antlr` plugin. But there's a bug. It includes `/build/generated-sources/` but excludes `/build/` which in turn excludes everything in it regardless if it's included or not.